# ¿Cómo introducir una función Set Tax en Solidity?

Tags: java, solidity, blockchain

Estoy aprendiendo desarrollo de Smart Contracts y, quería preguntar sobre si alguien sabe como introducir una función que establezca que cada transacción/transfer que se haga, dedique una parte de esta a añadirse a la Liquidez y a una Address de una wallet.

Estoy utilizando este standar de contrato para aprender ; https://github.com/mathwallet/BSC-Contracts/blob/main/Contracts/BEP20.sol

La función transfer la he editado y puesto de esta forma

```
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
    
    uint fee = (_value / 100) * 4;

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value - fee);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, admin, fee);
    return true;
  }
```

¿Cuál seria la forma correcta de poner el Tax para el liquidity pool del DEX?

Gracias :)

PD: Como pregunta complementaria si alguien lo sabe, ¿Hay alguna forma recomendada de función mint que no este activa siempre? Me refiero; que solo se pueda mintear la cantidad de Tokens 1 vez.

Answer (score 0):

te falta sumarle el balance al admin

```
balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value - fee);
balances[admin] = balances[admin].add(fee); //<------------------------
emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
emit Transfer(msg.sender, admin, fee);
```

la funcion simpre es _mint es privada te recomiendo hacer mint en el constructor.